# generate jquery mobile styling on ajax'd data-role

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ajax, jquery-mobile

I am using jquery mobile...

I have a button (data-role="button") which calls a javascript function which executes some ajax. This ajax then adds some HTML to the page. The returned HTML has a data-role="button" on it but it's not returning in the correct jquery mobile styling.

any ideas how to get the ajax to return the jquery in the correct styling without actually staticly putting in the jquery classes? I would perfer to use data-role for consistency.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must enhance manually the html because isn't any delegate to doing that.
Preferably immediately after adding html :)

```
 //document or place where are the buttons 
 $(document).trigger("create");
```

Answer (score 4):

This is works, but I want to create a button in loop. so there is many button I need and it is only one button create. Here is my `javascript` code :

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            datatype: "JSON",
            url: "/Home/SeferleriGetir",
            success: function (returnData) {
                if (returnData.ok) {
                    debugger;
                    for (var i = 0; i < returnData.data.length; i++) {
                        var html = "";
                        html += "<li>";
                        html += "<a href='' data-role='button' data-icon='arrow-r' data-iconpos='right' style='width: 100%'>";
                        html += "<div style='font-size: 14px; display: inline'>";
                        html += "<div style='text-align: left'><div style='width: 50%; display: inline-block; color: #ff0000'><div style='display: inline; width: 50%; text-align: left;'>" + returnData.data[i].firmaAdi + "</div></div>";
                        html += "<div style='width: 50%; display: inline-block'><div style='display: inline'>Fiyat :</div><div style='display: inline; text-align: right; color: #ff0000'>" + returnData.data[i].fiyat + " <span>TL</span></div></div></div>";
                        html += "<div style='text-align: left'><div style='width: 50%; display: inline-block'><div style='display: inline; text-align: left'>H. Saati :</div><div style='display: inline; color: #2192b8'>" + returnData.data[i].kalkisSaati + "</div></div>";
                        html += "<div style='width: 50%; display: inline-block'><div style='display: inline; text-align: right'>Süre :</div><div style='display: inline; color: #2192b8'>" + returnData.data[i].seferSuresi + "</div></div></div>";
                        html += "<div style='text-align: left'><div style='width: 50%; display: inline-block'><div style='display: inline'>O. Tipi:</div><div style='display: inline; color: #2192b8'>" + returnData.data[i].otobusTipi + "</div></div>";
                        html += "<div style='width: 50%; display: inline-block'><div style='display: inline'>S. Tipi:</div><div style='display: inline; color: #2192b8'>" + returnData.data[i].seferTipi + "</div></div></div>";
                        html += "<div style='text-align: left'><div style='display: inline;'>Güzergah :</div><div style='display: inline; color: #2192b8'>" + returnData.data[i].guzergah + "</div></div>";
                        html += "</div>"
                        html += "</a></li>";
                        $("#ulSeferler").append(html).trigger('create');
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    });
```

}